# ML-Engine, recommender systems , sideback in prevision step

Tags: prediction, google-cloud-ml

I'm quite new in the Tensorflow , senaking a peek inside some codes and tutorials at al I'm definitely a newby but one who whishes to learn. I'm having lot of fun with  TF but I cannot deny lot of headache too sometimes!
I'm currently working with ML -Engine and trying to deploy the model "movielens" for recommender systems, in regression version (the one who should allow me to compute user customized recommendations).

Well, sticking to the steps inside the README file, ranking (afterwards a couple of hitches) I was able reach out to deploy phase.
But my interest hovers over regression , for standard matrix-factorization recommender. I managed to successfully train my model with my DB, crammed the dimensionality inside the bytes limit that ML-Engine settle us.

This is the flags I used in pre-processing

```
python preprocess.py --input_dir $GCS_TRAINING_INPUT_DIR --output_dir $PREPROCESS_OUTPUT --percent_eval 20 --project_id $PROJECT --negative_sample_ratio 3 --eval_type regression --partition_random_seed 0 --cloud
```

The model is trained (and i add the flag --runtime-version 1.2), afterwards I'd wish to deploy my model for online predictions  but problems always occur; here below  with ERROR message:

> Not found: Op type not registered 'SparseFillEmptyRows'\n\n (Error
>   code: 0)

And really I  have no idea about in this very moment.Does anybody have any workaround please?

Thank

NB = the runtime-version flag I make use of it in both training and deploy

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you trained the model with a version of TensorFlow > 1.2 since SparseFillEmptyRows was not added until 1.3. `--runtime-version` 1.4 will be supported as soon as next week. You can either retrain your model using TF 1.2 or wait until next week to try and deploy.

Comment: First, thank for your reply! Glad to see that upgrading are going to arrive. Replying to your post , "Yes" I fufilled some test pitching , inside the setup.py file, either TENSORFLOW==1.3 and TENSORFLOW 1.2 . But another further issue is yet bothering me (a lot). When I made use of TENSORFLOW==1.2 I was able to reach out the prediction phase.Good! Thereof I immediatly pushed forward and inserted the flag --enable-bias inside my training because I need them.I train, make batch prediction and obtain an EMPTY json of predictions. What's the matter with this issue? Thank.